# How to decompose the variance of log book-to-market ratio into components using GMM in Vuolteenaho (1999)?

Tags: gmm

I'm reading [Vuolteenaho(1999)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=161911). In this article, the author investigates whether the variation in stock market valuation level is driven by expected future cash-flows or by expected returns. In part V.B and table 5, the author decomposes the variance of log book-to-market ratio into components using **GMM**. I know the variance decomposition comes from the equation (16) on page 10 of [Vuolteenaho(1999)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=161911). But I can't understand how to estimate this decomposition by **generalized method of moments**. Could anyone give some detailed information about this decomposition?

I know GMM is a method of parameter estimation, and I know how to decompose variance using VAR model (like [Campbell & Shiller (1988)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/1/3/195/1580239)). I just can't understand how to use GMM to variance decomposion.

Comment: He doesn't provide much detail but likely this is just a fancy way of saying that he estimates a theoretical population covariance by its sample value in data.

Comment: @fesman I guess so too but I'm not sure about it. Alter all, sample (co)variance is moment estimation of population (co)variance.